# checkbox properties using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

```
<input type="checkbox" id="var1" name="s_k" >
<input type="checkbox" id="var2" name="s_k">
<input type="checkbox" id="var3" name="s_k">
```

At some point the checkbox id=var1 is selected and disabled after a certain operation.Now then if id var2 and var3 checkbox are selected how to get the newly selected box id i.e, get ids of checkboxes which is not disabled using jquery

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Can you be a little bit more detailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i.e, get ids of checkboxes which is not disabled using jquery

I'm assuming your question is "how can I do that thing I just said?", in which case, you can combine the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selectors:

```
// Get all checkboxes that aren't disabled:
$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)')

// Get all selected checkboxes that aren't disabled:
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not(:disabled)')
```